# Why jQuery can't update input value in an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an input on event in jQuery.
when I change input value on clicking a button, it doesn't change.
when I get console.log() from value, it returns new value, But it doesn't change value in view.
here is my code:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.add_button').on('click', function() {
    $('.test_div').replaceWith('<button type="button" class="increase-input-test'+         
    ' onclick="changeInput()">change</button>' +
      '<input id="test_input" type="number" min="1" max="3" value="1" step="1">');
  })
})

function changeInput() {
  $('#test_input').val(2);
}
```

```css
.add_button, .test_div {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="add_button">click</button>
    <br>
    <div class="test_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also it didn't change with:

```
 $('#test_input').attr('value', 2); 
 document.getElemntById('test_input').value = 2;
```

Comment: You are dynamically creating the `input` with the `id="test_input"`. Are you creating more than one input with that id? Please add your HTML to the question as well

Comment: _"But it doesn't change value in view."_ - What "view"? -> Please add a [mcve]

Comment: I've added a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992). Please [edit] the question and update the HTML section

Comment: Ok, I've added html.

Answer (score 3):

How are you trying to change the value? It just works. Are you sure you have only ONE element with ID `test_input`? This is a quite common mistake, keep in mind that in an HTML page you should never have two elements with the same `id`.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.add_button').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     $('.teswt_div').html('<a type="button" class="increase-input-test onclick="changeInput()">change</a>' +
     '<input id="test_input" type="number" min="1" max="3" value="1" step="1">');
    })
}) 


function changeInput() {
    const lastValue = parseInt($('#test_input').val());
    $('#test_input').val(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add_button">add</button>
<div class="teswt_div"></div>

<button onclick="changeInput()">Change</button>
```

---

Answer updated with the new code from OP:
In this case, you forgot a `"` in your class, see:

```
$('.test_div').replaceWith('<button type="button" class="increase-input-test"'+
                                                                            ^
```

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.add_button').on('click', function() {
    $('.test_div').replaceWith('<button type="button" class="increase-input-test"'+         
    ' onclick="changeInput()">change</button>' +
      '<input id="test_input" type="number" min="1" max="3" value="1" step="1">');
  })
})

function changeInput() {
  $('#test_input').val(2);
}
```

```css
.add_button, .test_div {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="add_button">click</button>
    <br>
    <div class="test_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't answer the question if OP's code works as it is. Ask them to provide more details or flag them as not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I change id . But, still it doesn't work.

Comment: In this code you forgot a `"` when you define the button, see updated answer :)

Comment: If you inspect your code, this is how the button looks like: `<button type="button" class="increase-input-test onclick=" changeinput()"="">change</button>` and you can clearly see there's something wrong with double quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.add_button').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     $('.teswt_div').html('<a type="button" class="increase-input-test">change</a>' +
     '<input id="test_input" type="number" min="1" max="3" value="1" step="1">');
    $(".increase-input-test").on('click',function(){
     changeInput(); 
    });
    });
});

function changeInput() {
    const lastValue = parseInt($('#test_input').val());
    $('#test_input').val(2);
}
```

This works.
When adding the html try to add the on click listener via Jquery

A link to the [Pen](https://codepen.io/mrhussain0334/pen/dyGoXWd)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you just missed the ending of double quotes (") for a class attribute before onclick.

[image]

You can use like that if there is multiple..

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.add_button').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     $('.teswt_div').html('<a type="button" class="increase-input-test" onclick="changeInput(this)">change</a> ' +
     '<input class="test_input" type="number" min="1" max="3" value="1" step="1">');
    })
}) 


function changeInput(thisVar) { 
    var $testInput = $(thisVar).next('.test_input');
    const lastValue = parseInt($testInput.val()); alert($testInput.val());
    $testInput.val(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add_button">add</button>
<div class="teswt_div"></div>
```